# Raspi 3 Remote Desktop XRDP: No menu Bar

Tags: pi-3

I try to figure out why the menu bar is disappearing as I connect via remote desktop to my raspi. I found same issue [HERE](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=148583)

I followed the solution and I updated the security policy.
But I still can't see my menu bar. 
Does someone have the same problem?
I'm suffering since 2 weeks, after updating my raspi 3.

:)

Update:
I will install now Rasbian at a different SD, I will see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flashed my SD and reinstalled everything. Now its working fine. I think the issue came from the Pixel update.